# Using wp_insert_post and post_update_meta but need to fire save_post afterward

Tags: actions

I am using a calendar plugin. I have been using form data to create a new custom post type of calendar plugin and then update post meta custom fields for that calendar plugin. This works.

However there are other post meta that fired upon save_post action from the plugin classes.

I am trying to find a way to fire:

```
do_action( 'save_post', $post_id, $post, $update );
```

afterward. I have the $post_id but not the $post or $update. so that it fires all the methods as if I am clicking on save post in the admin.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `wp_update_post()` -https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Eg.

```
$my_post = array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
);

wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

The 'save_post' action should run when this function is called.

Comment: Yes, I used that, but still does not update all the post_meta (plugin and advanced custom fields) that update when I click "update" in the backend.

Comment: Oh, you said: "I have been using form data to create a new custom post type of calendar plugin and then update post meta custom fields for that calendar plugin. This works." - So does your code not work then?

Comment: When I use wp_insert_post and immediately update_post_meta, this works fine for the data I need to be there. But there are missing post meta that are created via the plugin classes or when you enter the same information (from insert_post, post_meta process that I created) and in the post edit page and click update/publish/draft